# Creating custom polymorphic models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I was interested in creating a model that could stand alone but could also belong to another model. So for example: I have an `Artist` that has many `Albums`. In addition to having many tracks (which is irrelevant for this case) it also can have many `Singles`. Here's the catch. There are some instances where a single doesn't belong to an album and is just used for promo (aka a promo single). So I thought I'd approach it using a polymorphic association:

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :albums
  has_many :singles, as: :singleable
end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  has_many :singles, as: :singleable
end

class Single < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :singleable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Not being entirely familiar with polymorphic associations I didn't know if this would be the correct way to setup what I had in mind of doing. Alternatively should I have created an entirely separate model called `PromoSingle` or create a dropdown that would define the single type?

Comment: Yup this is valid.
The downside to polymorphic is really in the query speed on the database side, but if you get to a point where that is an issue, you can compensate via caching.

This is the best example of a case for polymorphic relationships you can have. 

That said, your alternative is perfectly acceptable too. 

I would consider what your reporting and analytical requirements are going to be for the system, and then try to think ahead on those queries. That will be more important to deciding this than anything else.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying this. I'm happy as well as surprised I was able to guess this out on my first attempt.

Comment: Great. And remember, assuming you write a good test suite, if you need to change later, it should be relatively painless.

Comment: Why is it inappropriate to keep singles just as single-track albums? That would keep things simpler to handle.

Comment: @D-side Not really understanding what you mean.

Comment: @CarlEdwards actually I was trying to point out that this structure seems illogical to me, I didn't get it at first. My bad. So what you basically get is: a single cannot belong to album **and** artist at once, either only one or none of them. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @D-side From how you describe it I believe so. Basically a single can belong to an album of an artist. Alternatively still from that same artist, a single can exist as its own separate entity (without being owned under an album). Does the above association still work?

Comment: @CarlEdwards well... yeah, I think it should. I wouldn't make a polymorphic association though, I'd rather add 2 different `belongs_to` into a `Single` instead of just having one polymorphic. Not without a reason: think about retrieving all tracks of a specific artist, including ones inside his albums. Do you see the problem or I should explain further?

Comment: @D-side Yes, to clear things up I'd greatly appreciate it if you did.

Comment: @CarlEdwards To get a list of artist's tracks in your data structure you'd look up albums first and then singles through found albums. Then you'd look up singles directly referenced via polymorph. At least 3 queries. As with what I suggest, with artist referenced in its own `artist_id` with a corresponding `belongs_to` it would only take one: all singles with specific artist id. Well, this turned out lengthy... I'll write an answer with better formatted explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this case actually needs a polymorphic association. It should work, yes, but you'll soon find yourself in situations when you need to perform complicated searches to get seemingly simple results.

Polymorphic association should be used when association is **semantically** the same, but may involve different objects. It's not the case here, an artist is the one who created the track. But the album isn't.

This can cause trouble at least if you ever decide to fetch specific artist's tracks. Here's what ActiveRecord would have to do with your structure (including internal operations):

- Get list L1

  - Get an array A of `album_id`s, whose `artist_id` is X (a parameter)
  - Get all singles, whose `singleable_type` is `"Album"` **and** `singleable_id` is in the array of albums A, fetched before.
- Get list L2

  - Get all singles, whose `singleable_type` is `"Artist"` **and** `singleable_id` is X.
- Concatenate L1 and L2

Here is what I suggest you do.

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :albums
  has_many :singles
end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  has_many :singles
end

class Single < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :album
end
```

`PromoSingle`s fit well here too. Just because association is defined doesn't mean it should be present: it only means "it might be present, there is a place where we can put it".

Should you absolutely need it to be present (not here, somewhere else), you'd use a validation to ensure.

Otherwise, you may have items that don't belong to anyone, or, technically, belong to `nil` (Ruby level) or `NULL` (DB level). It's not bad if it makes sense.